# Using Wordpress User Credentials with a php script to send data to an iOS App

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, wordpress

So I've been working my *%& off for the past two days to try to make this work but I always get stuck at the same part : Comparing the computer password received from the iOS App with the hashed password stored in Wordpress DB.

A little background : Basically just a login page on an ios storyboard sending the email and password the user inputs to a php script that checks if the hashed password linked to the sent email is the same as the hashed version of the sent password.

Swift & iOS is't the problem here, so I'll spare you that code. I'm doing my testing using PostMan to send the HTTP POST Request with the correct parameters :

- Header --> Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body --> email : email@email.com & password : testpasswd

Now here is the original code for the login page :

```
<?php

require("Connection.php");
require("SQLDao.php");
$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$returnValue = array();

echo json_encode("Hello World");

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "There is a missing field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetailsWithPassword($email,$password);

if($userDetails) {
  $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
  $returnValue["message"] = "User logged in !";
  echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {
  $returnValue["status"] = "error";
  $returnValue["message"] = "User not found";
  echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

Most of `SQLDao.php` basically handles the SQL connection functions but also this function :

```
public function getUserDetailsWithPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
$returnValue = array();
$sql = "select id,user_email from vswp_users where user_email='" . $email . "' and user_pass='" .$userPassword . "'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
  if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($row)) {
      $returnValue = $row;
    }
  }
  return $returnValue;
}
```

But this code obviously checks the sent password to the Wordpress Hashed version, so it always returns false.

Through my research, I found this, but it didn't gave me a working solution :

Research no. 1 : include(phpass.php) + CheckPassword function
Where I would have something similar to this :

```
public function getUserDetailsWithHashedPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
  include_once("../wp-config.php");
  include_once("../wp-includes/class-phpass.php");
  $returnValue = array();
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vswp_users WHERE user_email = '$email'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

  $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

  $password_hashed = $row['user_pass'];

  $passwordMatch = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($userPassword, $password_hashed) || $password_hashed == md5($userPassword);

  if ($passwordMatch) {
    echo json_encode("Passwords match");
    $returnValue = TRUE;
  } else {
    echo json_encode("Passwords do not match");
    $returnValue = FALSE;
  }
  return $passwordMatch;
}
```

But this simply returns the "Hello World" but neither options of the if($passwordMatch) are shown.

I apologize for this long question, hopefully someone can point me towards the right direction to fix this.

Thanks for your help !!

EDIT 1 : Through some testing using `echo json_encode("Hello World");` I was able find that basically the script stops after the line --> ERASED SINCE NON-RELEVANT ANYMORE

EDIT 2 : I'm getting close, thanks to CBroe idea, I was able to find more information with proper PHP Reporting. I was able to make it work by putting the hashed password stored in the database directly in the login file as a value of `$storedPassword` and it worked. But now the only problem I'm facing is that while doing this with mysql, I'm getting the following error : 
`substr() expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given in /[...]/class-phpass.php`. It seems like I'm only missing a little something to convert the password from the mysql database to a string version of it. Here is my function :

```
public function getUserDetailsWithHashedPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
  require_once("/home/[hosting provider directories]/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpass.php");
  $returnValue = array();

  $sql = "select user_pass from vswp_users where user_email='" . $email . "'";
  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
  if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($row)) {
      $storedPassword = $row;
    }
  }
  $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
  $passwordMatch = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($userPassword, $storedPassword);

  if($passwordMatch === TRUE) {
    $returnValue = TRUE;
  } else {
    $returnValue = FALSE;
  }
  return $returnValue;
}
```

Thanks again !!

Comment: Enable proper PHP error reporting, and check the response in the browser's network panel.

Comment: Good idea. I found that there was indeed a problem with the `require_once()` urls.

Comment: But now i get another Error : "Class 'WP_User' not found in /[...]/pluggable.php. Any idea on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make it work. My last problem with the `$row` was that i didn't specify which array key I wanted to display. Here is working code if anybody ends up here and needs the working solution ! (Obviously [hosting provider directories] is just my internal file-system, change it to yours if need be)

```
public function getUserDetailsWithHashedPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
  require_once("/home/[hosting provider directories]/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpass.php");
  $returnValue = array();

  $sql = "select user_pass from vswp_users where user_email='" . $email . "'";
  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
  if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($row)) {
      $storedPassword = $row['user_pass'];
    }
  }
  $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
  $passwordMatch = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($userPassword, $storedPassword);

  if($passwordMatch === TRUE) {
    $returnValue = TRUE;
  } else {
    $returnValue = FALSE;
  }
  return $returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First fetch user details from database. And then check user's hashed password with plain text password.

To fetch user, you can try:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
```

Then:

```
if ( $user && wp_check_password( $userPassword, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ){
    echo json_encode("Passwords match");
    $returnValue = TRUE;
}
else{
    echo json_encode("Passwords do not match");
    $returnValue = FALSE;
}
```

related references:

[wp_check_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)

[get_user_by](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

Comment: And I assume I would need to also put `include_once("../wp-includes/pluggables.php");` ?

Comment: I tried this but i still don't seem to get a return value. "Hello Word" still shows but `$returnValue` is basically null.

Comment: You also need to include `wp-includes/pluggable.php` for calling `get_user_by(..)`. Please `var_dump($user)` and check what it returns. Also check what is the value of `wp_check_password( $userPassword, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID)` .

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I would like to improve it a little bit because it still works today, in 2021, and because the WordPress `class-phpass.php` file hasn't changed much since either.

The idea is to **safely** piggyback the WordPress credentials to allow users to log in on an external program, which can either reside in the same server or not (as far as the remote system has access to the WordPress database). For remote systems, a copy of the `class-phpass.php` file will be needed, otherwise, it can simply be requested from its original location in the WordPress path. Both cases will work just fine.

The changes I made are minimum but significant. Most importantly, I am using PDO instead of MySQLi.

I've also changed the function to identify if the login is being attempted with the **username** or the **e-mail**. It is a very small change, but it helps a lot and can be easily forced to one or another as needed.

Here the new function:

```
/** Request Wordpress portable PHP password hashing framework */
require_once "/[PATH-TO-WORDPRESS]/wp-includes/class-phpass.php";

/**
 * Validate Login using WordPress user's information
 * 
 * @param  string  $login     The user login information (can either be username or email).
 * @param  string  $password  The unhashed password for the proposed account.
 * @return boolean            Returns TRUE if login/password combination is valid, FALSE otherwise.
 */
function validateLogin(string $login, string $password): bool
{
  global $pdo;

  /** Identify if $login is an email or a username */
  $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? "user_email" : "user_login";

  /** Request data from MySQL using PDO */
  $request = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_pass FROM users WHERE {$field} = :login LIMIT 1");
  $request->bindValue(":login", $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $request->execute();
  $result = $request->fetchAll();

  /** If $result is empty, simply fail the validation */
  if (empty($result)) return false;

  /**
   * Process the received $password against the hashed password from the user identified as $login
   * in the WordPress database and return the result of the validation process.
   */
  $wordpress_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
  return $wordpress_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $result[0]['user_pass']);
}
```

Of course, I expect you will know how to set your PDO connection outside the function and *before* calling it (in this example, it is defined in the global variable `$pdo`). If you don't know much about PDO, here a great tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql

I've also included the `class-phpass.php` file *outside* the function. It ***can*** be included inside of it as it was done in the original answer, but I rather have it otherwise. :)

If for some reason you prefer to have the function *less* compliant with PHP 7+ or PHP 8, simply use it like this instead:

```
function validateLogin($login, $password) 
{  
  [...]
}
```