# iOS App recieving correctly-formatted JSON but still returning as not starting with array or object

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, parsing

So basically I have a login script on my server that returns a result depending on if the user credentials are correct or wrong, and I have an iOS App that sends data to that login script to return the correct or wrong result.

Here is the relevant part of my login page that shows the return code ($userDetails being the TRUE or FALSE check of correct or wrong credentials) :

```
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetailsWithHashedPassword($email,$password);
if($userDetails===TRUE) {
    $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
    $returnValue["message"] = "User logged in !";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {
    $returnValue["status"] = "error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "User not found";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
}
```

If anyone needs to see what that getUserDetailsWithHashedPassword() does, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193630/7010355)

Using Postman to test the HTTP POST, everything works fine, I get the correct result when posting email@email.com & testpassword in the body and using the correct Content-Type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) :

```
{"status":"error","message":"User not found"}
```

Now my iOS is supposed to interpret this with this code :

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let userEmail = emailLoginField.text
        let userPassword = passwordLoginField.text
        // Check for empty fields
        if((userEmail?.isEmpty)! || (userPassword?.isEmpty)!) { 
            // Display alert message
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required");     
            return ;
        }
        // Send user data to server side
        let myUrl = URL(string: "https://support.vincentsolutions.ca/userLogin.php");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print ("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                    print("result: \(resultValue)")
                    var isUserLoggedIn:Bool = false;
                    if(resultValue=="Success") {
                        // Login is successful
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();    
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccesful", sender: self)
                    }
                    var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    if(!isUserLoggedIn) {
                        messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!;
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        // Display alert message with confirmation.
                        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                        } 
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
                    });   
                }  
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("An error occured: \(error)")
            }
        }).resume()
```

Now I'm getting this error when I run the code from the iOS App :

> An error occured: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text
>   did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
>   set."

Does anyone see what could be wrong here ? I've tried looking for that error here on SO and on the internet but couldn't find anything related to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the response you are receiving from the URL probably not in correct JSON format. I will suggest you to do 2 things -

1. Try to NSLog the data and response
2. Try this

let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

Comment: Well I recieve the response exactly like this : {"status":"error","message":"User not found"}

Comment: When I'm using JSONLint at [link](http://jsonlint.com/) it says that the response is correctly formatted when returned using Postman.. Doesn't that mean that response is valid and it probably has something to do with the way the app handles the response ?

Comment: Also NSJSONReadingOptions doesn't seem to be working in Swift 3. Says it's undefined.

Comment: I was able to try your solution using `options : .allowFragments` which seems to be the correct Swift 3 syntax but now I'm getting another error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Comment: Finally made it work. A few problems here and there but .allowFragments made it work. Thanks !